# Unique number of the week in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If @weekly_updates returns two or more of the same number of weeks, we should get the last week_number. See the example. Thank you.

I change the method in the controller so.

```
@weekly_updates = current_user.user_updates.latest.offset(params[:offset] || 0).group_by {|u| u.week_number }.uniq
```

But it did not help.

Method in controllers.

```
def all
  @weekly_updates = current_user.user_updates.latest.offset(params[:offset] || 0)
end
```

Method in a model that calculates the week number:

```
class UserUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def week_number
    return 1 unless user.first_program_started_at.present?
    (((created_at.utc) - user.first_program_started_at.utc.beginning_of_day) / 86400 / 7).ceil.to_i || 1
  end
end
```

JSON:

```
json.weekly_updates @weekly_updates do |j1,  weekly_update|
  j1.week_number weekly_update.try(:week_number)
end
```

example:

```
"weekly_updates":
[
  {
    "id":25392,
    "created_at":"2014-03-21T10:13:54+04:00",
    "week_number":2
  }
  ,
  {
    "id":25393,
    "created_at":"2014-03-20T23:59:59+04:00",
    "week_number":2
  }
  {
    "id":25394,
    "created_at":"2014-03-26T23:59:59+04:00",
    "week_number":3
  }
]
```

should get this.

```
"weekly_updates":
[
  {
    "id":25393,
    "created_at":"2014-03-20T23:59:59+04:00",
    "week_number":2
  }
  {
    "id":25394,
    "created_at":"2014-03-26T23:59:59+04:00",
    "week_number":3
  }
]
```

Comment: What happens if you remove .uniq after the group_by call?

Comment: @rails4guides.com `'2' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.`